# updating array in object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object defined like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    lists: ["Dogs", "Cats"],
    items: {Dogs:[], Cats:[]}
    };
  }

  handleAddItem(item) {
    console.log(this.props.idName);
    console.log(item);
  }
```

I have the variable

```
console.log(this.props.idName)// output: Dogs
console.log(item);// output {name: "lofi"}
```

I don't know how to update the object items{} to make it becоme like this:

```
items{Dogs:[{name: "lofi"}], Cats:[]}
```

Comment: Not answering your question, but try to keep your flat is a good practice.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842454/why-should-i-keep-the-state-flat

Comment: @konekoya thank you

Answer (score 1):

To update a nested Array substate, you can use the spread operator to append elements

```
handleAddItem = item => {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
    items: {
      ...prevState.items,
      [props.idName]: [
        ...prevState.items[props.idName],
        item
      ]
    }
  }))
}
```

Comment: It is better to use setState with callback function in such case:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: From React docs - `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

Comment: yeah. for things like incrementing etc I see the point, how would your solution look like? I don't see a more "atomic" way to do it.

Comment: I get this error   App.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: handleAddItem is missing the "this" context. Write the declaration `handleAddItem = item => {}` as I did, or bind the function correctly to this.

Comment: @amaj Thanks for pointing this out! Good watch! I updated the code accordingly. You example is not using the props from the updater function, so you may fix your code as well :)

Answer (score 1):

What about something like that

```
handleAddItem(item) {
    this.setState((s, p) => ({
        items: {
            ...s.items,
            [p.idName]: s.items[p.idName].concat([item])
        }
    }))
}
```

Few comments:

- `setState` can take function, as parameter you got old state value
- `[idName]: value` dynamically updates prop `idName`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    lists: ["Dogs", "Cats"],
    items: {Dogs:[], Cats:[]}
    };
  }

  handleAddItem(item) {
    console.log(this.props.idName);
    console.log(item);
    let oldItems = this.state.items;
    oldItems[this.props.idName].push(item);
    // Update new state for items
    this.setState({
      items: {...this.state.items}
    })

  }
```

Comment: Am updating the previous state variable to be make it ready to update for the next state. You can see spread operator in the this.setState call which updates it how react wants. Let me update the answer to make it clear.

Comment: You can pass function in setState, where you have access to oldState and you don't have to save previous state value, check docs:
reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: This may corrupt data! The setState call would overwrite the other category!

Comment: @lipp. How so ?

Comment: @agent_hunt `this.state.items` gets replaced entirely. If `this.state.items.Cats = [{name: 'foo'}]` and `idName = 'Dogs'`, the 'Cats' get removed. That said: I just noticed, that your are missing "one level". It is e.g. this.state.items.Cats = [{name: 'foo'}] ... and not this.state.items = [{name: 'foo'}]

Comment: @lipp `   let oldItems = this.state.items;
    oldItems[this.props.idName].push(item);` will add items only to the category. So for ex: if idName = Dogs .  oldItems['Dogs'].push(item) . Am not touching anything related to Cats.   I dont see how this.setState will corrupt data .

Comment: @agent_hunt this.state.items = {Cats: [], Dogs: []}. items is an object with two fields (as from the constructor). You are assigning an array to items => this.state.items = [].