# How is it possible that after API call and setState, some elements of the same object are accessible, while others aren't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, error-handling, render

So here's some code

```
componentWillMount = () => {
    var URL = 'http://localhost:8000/requests'
    axios({
        url: URL,
        method: 'post', 
        data: {
            message: 'getImages'
        }
    }).then(res => {
        this.setState({currentImage: res.data.picsData[this.props.match.params.imageId]})
    })
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="image-component-wrapper">
            <img src={'../content/' + this.state.currentImage.fileName} /> 
            <div className="image-meta">
                <p className='image-metadescription'{this.state.currentImage.description</p>
                <p className='image-meta-author'>Uploaded by:
                <i className='image-meta-author-name'>{this.state.currentImage.author}</i></p>
                <div className='image-meta-tags'>
                    Tags:
                    {this.state.currentImage.tags.map(tag => <p>{tag}</p>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The image displays as it should. The two P tags and the I tag also but I can't get the array of tags to display at all. It gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

They are contained in the same state object so I don't understand how it's possible. The array is there I'm sure!

Comment: Can you show the entire component including the initial state assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Allthough sequence of 1. componentWillMount 2. render is correct, your async initialization of this.state.currentImage seems to be the problem no?

It will render before the axios call has finished and actually set the data to state.

A simple fix is to add undef check:

```
{this.state.currentImage.tags && this.state.currentImage.tags.map(tag => <p>{tag}</p>)}
```

Comment: No, because other items in this.state.currentImage like 'description' and 'author' renders fine, and also the image but not the array. They are in the same currentImage they come together from the axios call. Tried your fix, same error.

Comment: I should've added the check to currentImage.tags for one thing! But yes, perhaps its an issue in how the tags are actually coming in. Could you debug the object to see how the the tags array looks like?

Comment: I already debugged that came before the question. Thats why I'm sure the array is there.
Here's the output of console.log(res.data.picsData[this.props.match.params.imageId].tags)
https://i.ibb.co/G94n1RS/Screenshot-at-2019-12-22-02-02-43.png

Comment: Not sure why. Did you try this.state.currentImage.tags &&, maybe theres a extra render were not seeing and this check would allow for rerender with actual data..

Comment: Figured it out. The problem was it rendered multiple times but the first time it rendered the state wasn't set yet but since the array.map is a function that gave an error.

Comment: Nice job. I also tested it with fiddle, and verified it renders once before the async call is done. This was my first guess too.

Answer (score 1):

```js
this.state.currentImage.tags.map(tag => <p>{tag}</p>)
```

You're trying to access `this.state.currentImage.tags.map` here but your initial state is defined as

```js
this.state = { currentImage: {} }
```

Which means that `this.state.currentImage.tags` is undefined which you can also see in the error message you're getting when you try to call `tags.map`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

To fix this you would have to make sure that you're defining everything you're using in your state in your constructor like

```js
this.state = {
  currentImage: {
    author: "",
    description: "",
    tags: []
    // etc
  }
}
```

You might also want to flatten your state here, which is something you could read more about [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842454/why-should-i-keep-the-state-flat)

Comment: Yes that's how i fixed it actually i defined currentImage as null in state and did an if check in render to skip rendering if still null

Answer (score 0):

@Xetera

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addPics, setCurrentPic } from '../../redux/actions';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class ImageComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { currentImage: {}, imageId: this.props.match.params.imageId }
    }
    componentWillMount = () => {
        var URL = 'http://localhost:8000/requests'
        axios({
            url: URL,
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                message: 'getImages'
            }
        }).then(res => {
            this.setState({ currentImage: res.data.picsData[this.props.match.params.imageId] })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="image-component-wrapper">
                <img src={'../content/' + this.state.currentImage.fileName} />
                <div className="image-meta">
                    <p className='image-meta-description'>{this.state.currentImage.description}</p>
                    <p className='image-meta-author'>Uploaded by:
        <i className='image-meta-author-name'>{this.state.currentImage.author}</i></p>
                    <div className='image-meta-tags'>
                        Tags:
                        {this.state.currentImage.tags.map(tag => <p>{tag}</p>)}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state)
    return { pics: state.pics, pic: state.pic }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addPics, setCurrentPic })(ImageComp)
```